# How to get a list of built-in color names?

Tags: graphics, color

I find myself sometimes doing something like `ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Violet]`, just to discover that `Violet` is not recognized like `Blue`, `Red`, and so on...

How can I ask *Mathematica* to print a list of all the built-in named colors?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Colors.html

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `Blue` (or any other color), you'll see a link to the [Colors Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Colors.html) at the bottom. In there, you'll find a section of named colors. [Edit: Apparently @Kuba was faster - I'm still leaving this here as a reference of how to find it]

Comment: sorry, I must be tired... thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get a list of the known system colors:

```
Quiet[Select[Names["System`*"],
             Attributes[#] === {Protected} && ColorQ[ToExpression[#]] &]]
  {"Black", "Blue", "Brown", "Cyan", "Gray", "Green", "LightBlue", "LightBrown",
   "LightCyan", "LightGray", "LightGreen", "LightMagenta", "LightOrange",
   "LightPink", "LightPurple", "LightRed", "LightYellow", "Magenta", "Orange",
   "Pink", "Purple", "Red", "Transparent", "White", "Yellow"}
```

---

If you really want a violet color, you can use either `ColorData["Legacy", "Violet"]` (corresponding to the colors in the old `` Graphics`Colors`﻿ `` package) or `ColorData["Crayola", "Violet"]`. To get a list of the supported colors for these, you can do `ColorData["Legacy", "ColorRules"]` (and similarly for `"Crayola"`).

Answer (score 4):

```
wlNamedColors =  Interpreter`InternalColor`PackagePrivate`$WLNamedColors;

Multicolumn[Normal @ KeyMap[#[[2]]& @* Apply[List]] @ 
  Association @ wlNamedColors, 5]
```

[image]

```
w3cNamedColors = Interpreter`InternalColor`PackagePrivate`$W3CNamedColors;

Multicolumn[Normal @ KeyMap[#[[2]]& @* Apply[List]] @ 
  Association @ w3cNamedColors, 5]
```

[image]

You can also use `Entity`:

```
entityColor = EntityList["Color"];

Length @ entityColor
```

> ```
> 10408
> ```

```
SeedRandom[7777];
rs = RandomSample[entityColor, 20]

Grid[{#["CanonicalName"], #["Value"]} & /@ rs]
```

[image]