# How to obtain the names of a list of named colors?

Tags: color

I would like to obtain a framed table, within which the first row contains round color swatches, while the second row contains the corresponding color name.
From the document, `Red` is a symbol. So I tried to use `SymbolName[Red]` to obtain the name but it returned an error ("Argument Red at position 1 is expected to be a symbol").

The only way I can think of is:

```
Grid[{Graphics[{#, Disk[]}] & /@ {Red, Magenta, Pink}, {"Red", "Magenta", "Pink"}}, Frame -> All]
```

Comment: [154242](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154242/how-to-get-a-list-of-built-in-color-names) should resolve it.

Comment: The linked answer is more complicated than simply tying all the names of colors. @Syed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found an easier way:

```
{Red, LightGray, Magenta} // HoldForm // ToString
```

Now we can use StringSplit[%, {"{", "}", ","}] to change the string back to list of color names.

Comment: `{Red, LightGray, Magenta} // HoldForm // ToString; SymbolName[#] & /@ %`  gives  `"{Red, LightGray, Magenta}"`. Is this what you want?

Comment: {Red, LightGray, Magenta} // HoldForm // ToString alone simply gives the text form of {Red, LightGray, Magenta} @kglr

Comment: My mistake, the string shall be matipulated to list first. @kglr

Answer (score 7):

**Update 2:**

TDIL (from metroidman's comment) about [`ToEntity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToEntity.html).

Here is a  way to use it to get string names of Wolfram Language system colors:

```
ClearAll[clrName]
clrName = Function[, 
 Quiet[Check[Capitalize@ToEntity[#]["Name"], 
   Style[StringForm["`` is not a WL color.", #], Darker@Red]]], 
{HoldFirst, Listable}];
```

***Examples:***

```
clrName @ Red
```

> ```
> "Red"
> ```

```
clrName @ LightBrown
```

> ```
> "LightBrown"
> ```

```
clrName @ blah
```

> [image]

```
clrName @ {Red, Green, Cyan, LightBrown}
```

> {"Red", "Green", "Cyan", "LightBrown"}

Alternatively, we can define `clrName` using `Last[#, #] & @ ToEntity[#]["CanonicalName"]` instead of `Capitalize @ ToEntity[#]["Name"]`.

**Update:**

```
wLColorNames =  Map[#[[2]] & @* Apply[List]]@
  Association @ Map[Reverse] @
  Interpreter`InternalColor`PackagePrivate`$WLNamedColors
```

[image]

```
wLColorNames /@ {Red, Yellow, Magenta}
```

> ```
> {"Red", "Yellow", "Magenta"}
> ```

```
Lookup[{Red, Yellow, Magenta}] @ wLColorNames
```

> ```
> {"Red", "Yellow", "Magenta"}
> ```

```
Grid[{Labeled[Graphics[{#, Disk[]}], wLColorNames@#,  Bottom] & /@ 
 {Red, Magenta, Pink, Cyan}}, 
Frame -> All]
```

[image]

```
Grid[Partition[#, 5] & @
  KeyValueMap[
   Labeled[
    Graphics[{#, EdgeForm[Gray], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 150], 
    #2, Bottom]&] @
  wLColorNames, 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
legacyColors = Association @ ColorData["Legacy", "ColorRules"];

Grid[Partition[
 KeyValueMap[Labeled[Graphics[{#2, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 90], #, Bottom] &] @ 
  legacyColors,
 10], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry but it is not the correct answer. My question can be put in a simple way: how to get the name from the named color? For example, given {Red, Green}, how to transform such list to the text list of {Red, Green}? @kglr

Comment: @metroidman, please see the update.

Comment: I think I have come out an easier way of transforming named color Red into text Red. ToEntity[Red][[2]][[2]]. But pure function does not work as expected if it is a list. ToEntity[#][[2]][[2]] & /@ {Red, Green, Blue} gives the RGB value instead of the name. @kglr

Comment: ToEntity[LightBrown][[2]][[2]] does not work. Another way is to use EntityValue[ToEntity[LightBrown], "Name"], which works for all named colors.

Comment: @metroidman, I didn't about `ToEntity`. Posted an update with a way to make your method work with a list of colors.

Answer (score 5):

Departing from Syed's answer, I would suggest to create an `Association` of names and colors:

```
cas =
  AssociationThread[
   ColorData["Legacy", "Range"][[1]],
   ColorData["Legacy", "ColorList"]];

cas // Dataset
```

[image]

A simple query

```
cas["Banana"]
```

[image]

A more complex query

```
KeySelect[cas, StringMatchQ["*Blue*"]] // Dataset
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
cols = ColorData["Legacy", "ColorList"];
lut = Thread[cols -> First@ColorData["Legacy", "Range"]];

Column[{Graphics[{#, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> Tiny], Lookup[lut, #]}
     , Alignment -> Center] & /@ cols // Partition[#, UpTo[6]] & // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[toColorName]

toColorName = Function[, 
   First @ First @
     Replace[OwnValues[#], 
      Verbatim[HoldPattern][a_] :> SymbolName[Unevaluated @ a], 
      All], {Listable, HoldFirst}];
```

***Examples:***

```
toColorName @ Red
```

> ```
> "Red"
> ```

```
toColorName @ LightGreen
```

> ```
> "LightGreen"
> ```

```
toColorName @ {Green, LightBrown, Red, Cyan}
```

> ```
> {"Green", "LightBrown", "Red", "Cyan"}
> ```